# Loading GIFs in iOS consumes too much memory

Tags: ios, swift, memory, animated-gif

I've been testing around a lot of open-source animated-gif libraries to load `GIF` files into our `Swift` project.

Most of them claim to be *high-performance* libraries, however, whenever I load an animated gif my application uses around 8MB of memory.

The problem is that this dedicated memory space seems to never be released. We can see it growing linearly:

[image]

And it makes me wonder if I'm doing the right thing here. Is this behavior correct, or is it potentially bad for the user?

Comment: Are you experiencing this with the simulator, or on an actual device?

Comment: Also what 3rd party libraries are you using?

Comment: @Pierce this is coming from a real device. And it looks like a common behavior since I already tried GIFU, SwiftyGif and a few others.

Comment: 8MB seems outrageous to me! It makes me think there must be some problem. I have a phone interview here in ten minutes, but when that's over if nobody has helped you solve your problem I'll go profile an app I use with SwiftGIF and tell you what I get as far as memory allocation

Comment: Nitpick: Memory usage in your graph is not growing [exponentially](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function), but [linearly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_equation).

Comment: 8MB seems a lot to me too. But take a look at this.. https://github.com/kirualex/SwiftyGif#benchmark . It felt like it's "normal".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you would need to remove the Gif images manually for them to get cleared from the memory.

**Example:** gifViwer can be your Gif Viewer in this example

```
self.gifViewer.removeFromSuperview()
self.gifViewer = nil
```

if you had to assign a delegate then you can also add

```
self.gifViewer.Delegate = nil
```

**Note:** you need to run this when the `viewControler` is being completely unloaded as the app will start looking for `gifViewer` in the view while it has been removed. if you need to clear the gif image from the memory without unloading the view then I suggest to use the steps above and then adding the view to the superView programatically. this is not going to work with the interface designer and IBOutlets

```
let gifViewer = yourGifViewerClass(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 20, width: self.view / 2, height: self.view / 2))
    //  setup your gifViewer
```

Comment: Removing from superView is enough. Object was not being released from memory (and I have no idea why I need to force).

Comment: Objects will only get released from memory if usage gets really high and the `didReceiveMemoryWarning` is called @Machado

Comment: Thank you @Mentos, but this is being instantiated inside an Dialog which fires a method to remove all views from superView before closing. That's why I found it strange.

Comment: Nice solution, thanks a lot. I was going crazy after hours of navigating in Instruments, failing to find what went wrong... // Note that this solution also works for macOS apps (which was my case, I had to remove the GIF view from its superview just before the window closes).